# Recover workspace variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, workspace

Is it possible to recover the workspace variable has been just deleted? Representative SVM-training model was accidentally deleted by another .m file starting with the command:

```
clear all;
```

Comment: Nope... sorry, you're SOL. Very much like conventional compiled languages like C or C++, as soon as you free memory or delete an instance of a class, it's gone forever.  Not doing this behaviour would be subject to very bad memory leaks or unexpected behaviour. Think of the opposite idea. If you are clearing memory and **relying** on the fact that it's cleared, you wouldn't want it to linger around and be referenced later. Having this linger around when you expect it not to would also be a bad idea as memory may be quickly consumed up. `tl;dr`: no.

Comment: Thanks for full answer! I was convinced that Matlab is a research tool rather than a programming one. Even the same Workspace window is so useful to simplify life and shorten research time.

Comment: That was in the past. I'd consider it a programming language with a full suite of tools available for both research and for deploying applications.

Comment: May be. But it requires a wide additional learning in order to use it effectively as a part of .NET applications, for instance. It begins from forced using `4-Gigabyte Tuning` with such an instruction `BCDEdit /set increaseuserva 3072` in x86 platforms. By the way, most of medical equipment uses x86 architecture and the appropriate embedded operational systems (more cheap).